# How to prevent Google from crawling UserDir URLs (but not the real domain)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

We have clients who build their site on a UserDir URL before their real domain goes live. The UserDir URL is always in the format:

http://1.2.3.4/~johndoe

Sometimes, Google crawls these UserDir URLs and the temporary site will show up in results even after the site is live on http://johndoe.com

So, once a client is live on http://johndoe.com, **how can I prevent Google from crawling the UserDir address**?

(of course, I need Google to crawl the real domain because SEO is important to our clients)

Comment: Have you tried using a [robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) on 1.2.3.4?

Comment: Well, both the temp URL and real domain point to the same httpdocs ...

Answer (score 0):

I use the canonical tag for this purpose.  If you put the canonical tag on the index.html file like such:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://johndoe.com/" />
```

Then when Googlebot finds it at http://1.2.3.4/~johndoe it will know that it is a duplicate of http://johndoe.com/ and Google will index the correct one. Googlebot will see the same tag when it crawls the real site and not have a problem with the self-referential canonical.